# How to sum a set of aggregated output and format its order simultaneously

Tags: mysql

I hope i'm asking he right question, but i want to sum a set of aggregated output and format its order simultaneously.

Sample table:

```
Entity Type   Value
A      1      200
B      1      500
C      0      350
B      0      150
D      0      200
C      1      100
A      1      50
A      1      350
D      1      100
E      1      150
```

Expected Output:

```
Entity    diff_positive    diff_negative
A         600
B         350
E         150
C                          250
D                          100
------------------------------
total     500              350
```

With help, i've been able to sum all Entity'A' of Type'1' then subtract from the result, the sum of Entity'A' of type'0'. While simultaneously populating a table to show where this difference is positive or negative.
Currently this is what i have;

```
select entity,
greatest(sum(case when type = 1 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_positive,
greatest(sum(case when type = 0 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_negative    
from t
group by entity
ORDER BY diff-negative, entity ASC;
```

Current Output:

```
Entity    diff_positive    diff_negative
A         600
B         350
E         150
D                          100
C                          250
```

I require entity'C' to appear before entity'D' as demonstrated in the expected output.

Also, to get the total; i have tried to sum() the Diff-Positive and Diff-Negative as follows.

```
select entity,
sum(greatest(sum(case when type = 1 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_positive),
sum(greatest(sum(case when type = 0 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_positive)
from t
group by entity;
```

I get Error;

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'diff_positive), sum(greatest(sum(case when type = 0 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_negative)
```

I have a feeling i should be able to figure it out from this point, but i'm quite new to mysql

Comment: in your first query, you have a `;` after the `group by`, so the `order by` is not part of the select statement

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It appears to depend on the value of the `type` column (1=+ve, 0=-ve).  Though why the `value` column isn't just stored as +ve/-ve and the `type` column removed is beyond me.

Comment: @eggyal: It is simply the requirement of my data presentation.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to couple your data model to your presentation model—what happens if one changes?

Comment: @eggyal: By data presentation, i actually mean presentation model. I am actually using php to query the DB. This query is does not in anyway alter my data model.

Comment: I know.  That's what I meant too.  Don't couple your data storage model to your presentation model.  Store in the model that is most suited to storage and retrieval, then translate to the model that is most suited to presentation within your application.

Comment: @eggyal: Ok. But i have no experience with that, so the idea is still fuzzy. How do you suggest i go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the total, use `with rollup`.  To get the ordering, you can use `order by` . . . the zero value will go last:

```
select entity,
       greatest(sum(case when type = 1 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_positive,
       greatest(sum(case when type = 0 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_negative    
from t
group by entity
order by diff_positive desc, diff_negative asc;
```

An alternative `order by` is:

```
order by sum(case when type = 1 then value else - value end)
```

By using the expression you can use only one key in the `order by`.

EDIT:

To get the rollup to work use two levels of aggregation:

```
select entity, sum(diff_positive) as diff_positive,
       sum(diff_negative) as diff_negative)
from (select entity,
             greatest(sum(case when type = 1 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_positive,
             greatest(sum(case when type = 0 then value else - value end), 0) as diff_negative    
      from t
      group by entity
     ) e
group by entity with rollup
order by diff_positive desc, diff_negative asc;
```

The outer `group by` doesn't really do anything except the `rollup`.

Comment: Using rollup gives the following error #1221 - Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: Using Rollup without (order by diff_positive desc, diff_negative asc) works but produces the wrong sum. This is because it Rollsup everything in the diff_positive column, including the negative values generated by the CASE statement, which was initially eliminated by the GREATER statement comparison. How can i get only the positive values rolled up?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, [I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320248/how-to-sum-a-set-of-aggregated-output-and-format-its-order-simultaneously#comment62160289_37320248):

> Though why the `value` column isn't just stored as +ve/-ve and the `type` column removed is beyond me.

And after some discussion, [you replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320248/how-to-sum-a-set-of-aggregated-output-and-format-its-order-simultaneously#comment62169664_37320248):

> Ok. But i have no experience with that, so the idea is still fuzzy. How do you suggest i go about implementing this?

1. First, update the values in `value`:

   ```sql
   UPDATE t SET value = -value WHERE type = 0;
   ```
2. Second, remove the `type` column:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE t DROP type;
   ```
3. Obtain the results your application requires, performing translation to a presentation model within your application code.  For example, using PDO one could do the following:

   ```php
   $stmt = $pdo->query('
     SELECT   entity, SUM(value) AS diff
     FROM     t
     GROUP BY entity
     ORDER BY diff DESC
   ');

   $total_positive = $total_negative = 0;

   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     if ($row['diff'] > 0) {
       // handle positive diff here as before

       $total_positive += $row['diff'];
     } else {
       // handle negative diff here as before

       $total_negative += $row['diff'];
     }
   }
   ```

It may also be worth noting that, in both your old model and this proposed one, each `entity` can only be one of -ve *or* +ve throughout.  Accordingly the `type` in your old model (and, strictly speaking, the sign of `value` in this new one) is dependent on `entity`—so repeating it in this table violates [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).

Comment: This is interesting stuff. I didn't understand your meaning or the implementation of storing the 'value' as +ve/-ve and removing 'type' until now. I can already see the up-side of this proposed model. I will surely explore this angle in future. I wish i don't have to do this now though because it will demand a lot of re-writing of my other code to fully implement this.

Comment: This is not my original question. But i accept this answer because its actually what i need. And it worked for me well. Thnx.